# Default search in Google Chrome locked to smartsputnik

Tags: google-chrome, search-engine

I have deleted and created a new user, cleared history, cleared cache even uninstalled and then installed chrome again, but nothing. Any solution for that.
I have seen some software while searching on different websites but em afraid they can also b some sort of malware, what should i do, any Help......

Comment: A simple Google search for "smartsputnik" reveals that it is indeed some sort of malware.

Comment: so whats the solution for that. I have updated antivirus with web protection i have scanned my whole computer, no threats found, but still not able to get rid of.....

Comment: Have you tried searching for a solution? "Antivirus" software is rarely reliable.

Comment: yup..but i didn't got any solution ....a few of the solutions were to make changes in the registry but at the end they propose some sort of software to fix the registry back again. those are are malicious softwares.

Answer (score 0):

You can change registry in Windows by running regedit.exe, usually you don't need external tools for that. A quick search for "smartsputnik"  in regedit reveals that some Chrome-related entry contains a link to it. Changing it back to what it should be, that is e.g. what Chrome uses for its search query, should fix the issue. For my colleague it was

`{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}`

After the change, you can delete the offender from search engines as well, that seemed to be impossible while it was the default. That helped to restore Chrome itself, but [this blog post](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-smartsputnik-ru/) says it will also append "http://smartsputnik.ru/?ri=1&uid=" as the argument to random shortcuts. That could be devious, but I've not observed that yet, will check and see.

BTW, my colleague did not install any software recently, so it looks like this malware learned a new trick.